# Open file in specific folder

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script, jsx

I know my filename to open and destination where this file is. 
I can't find function to open specific file as new document in photoshop.

I have:

```
#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();
main();
function main(){

var name; 
var L;

name = app.activeDocument.name;

L = name.length;
L = L - 4;
name = name.substr(0, L);
name = name+"_sufix.png"; 
};
```

So how can I open file named name?

Comment: Did you try? open(name)

Answer (score 0):

`app.activeDocument.name` would assume you have already opened the image document

Try adding this:

```
fileRef = "C:\\directory1\\name.png"
```

app.open(fileRef)

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble with this, update your var name, to say nameRef and it will work correctly.